# objects instances returning none using django bulk_create()

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am trying to bulk insert data into the database but upon appending these instances i find they are none

**model**

```
 class Seekerskillset(models.Model):
        skill_set = models.ForeignKey(Skillset, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        seeker = models.ForeignKey(SeekerProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        skill_level = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    
        class Meta:
            verbose_name = 'Seeker skill set'
```

**my view**

```
 for skill_nme, skill_lvl in zip(skill_name, skill_level):
        skill_set = Skillset.objects.get(skill_name=skill_nme)
        seeker_skll.append(Seekerskillset(
            skill_set=skill_set, skill_level=skill_lvl, seeker=user))
        print(seeker_skll)
  

    seeker_bulk = Seekerskillset.objects.bulk_create(seeker_skll)
    print('after insertion',seeker_bulk)
    return redirect('/users/dashboard')
```

**trace**

```
<class 'seekerbuilder.models.SeekerProfile'>
[<Seekerskillset: Seekerskillset object (None)>, <Seekerskillset: Seekerskillset object (None)>, <Seekerskillset: Seekerskillset object (None)>, <Seekerskillset: Seekerskillset object (None)>]
after insertion [<Seekerskillset: Seekerskillset object (None)>, <Seekerskillset: Seekerskillset object (None)>, <Seekerskillset: Seekerskillset object (None)>, <Seekerskillset: Seekerskillset object (None)>]
[19/Jul/2021 14:27:12] "POST /users/app_det/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[19/Jul/2021 14:27:12] "GET /users/dashboard HTTP/1.1" 301 0
```

Comment: The `None` iss the value for the primary key. When doing a bulk create, for most databases, it will not set the primary keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The item between brackets (here `(None)`) is the *primary key* of the object.  So if you do not override the `__str__` or `__repr__` method of the model, it will print this with:

```
<ModelName: ModelName object (pk)>
```

When doing a [**`.bulk_create(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) for some databases, Django is able to retrieve the primary key, for other databases that is not possible (since the database for example does not contain any logic to return values when creating an object). As is specified by [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create):

> If the model's primary key is an `AutoField`, the primary key attribute can **only be retrieved on certain databases** (currently PostgreSQL, MariaDB 10.5+, and SQLite 3.35+). On other databases, it will not be set.

Comment: thankyou soo much! i had trouble understanding that

Comment: Does SQLite still work? I use it with SQLite and doesn't work. In Django-doc it says "If the model’s primary key is an AutoField, the primary key attribute can only be retrieved on certain databases (currently PostgreSQL and MariaDB 10.5+). On other databases, it will not be set."

Comment: @nogabemist: as of Django-4.0, it will work again, as is specified in the documentation: "*Support for the fetching primary key attributes on SQLite 3.35+ was added.*"